# Neo4J Cypher to get Combinations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find a way to group combinations together. 
Say we have nodes of type person, hobby, place, city. Say the graph has the following relations (merged)

```
CREATE
  (Joe:Person {name: 'Joe'}),
  (hike:Hobby {name: 'hike'}),
  (eat:Hobby {name: 'eat'}),
  (drink:Hobby {name: 'drink'}),
  (Mountain:Place {name: 'Mountain'}),
  (Lake:Place {name: 'Lake'}),
  (DavesBarGrill:Place {name: 'Daves BarGrill'}),
  (Diner:Place {name: 'Diner'}),
  (Lounge:Place {name: 'Lounge'}),
  (DiveBar:Place {name: 'Dive Bar'}),
  (Joe)-[:likes]->(hike),
  (Joe)-[:likes]->(eat),
  (Joe)-[:likes]->(drink),
  (hike)-[:canDoAt]->(Mountain),
  (hike)-[:canDoAt]->(Lake),
  (eat)-[:canDoAt]->(DavesBarGrill),
  (eat)-[:canDoAt]->(Diner),
  (drink)-[:canDoAt]->(Lounge),
  (drink)-[:canDoAt]->(DiveBar)
```

For a day planned to do each of his hobbies once, there are 8 combinations of places to hike and eat and drink. I want to be able to capture this in a query.

The naive approach,

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:likes]->(h:Hobby)-[:canDoAt]->(pl:Place)
RETURN p, h, pl
```

will at best be able to group by person and hobby, which will cause rows of the same hobby to be grouped together. what i want is to somehow group by combos, i.e.:

```
//Joe Combo 1// Joe,hike,Mountain
                Joe,eat,Daves
                Joe,drink,Lounge
//Joe Combo 2// Joe,hike,Lake  
                Joe,eat,Daves
                Joe,drink,Lounge
```

Is there a way to somehow assign a number to all path matches and then use that assignment to sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very good question! I don't have the whole solution yet, but some thoughts: as Martin Preusse said, we are looking to generate a Cartesian product.

This is difficult, but you can workaround it by a lot of hacking, including using a double-reduce:

```
WITH [['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3], [true, false]] AS hs
WITH hs, size(hs) AS numberOfHobbys, reduce(acc = 1, h in hs | acc * size(h)) AS numberOfCombinations, extract(h IN hs | length(h)) AS hLengths
WITH hs, hLengths, numberOfHobbys, range(0, numberOfCombinations-1) AS combinationIndexes
UNWIND combinationIndexes AS combinationIndex
WITH
  combinationIndex,
  reduce(acc = [], i in range(0, numberOfHobbys-1) |
    acc + toInt(combinationIndex/(reduce(acc2 = 1, j in range(0, i-1) | acc2 * hLengths[j]))) % hLengths[i]
  ) AS indices,
  reduce(acc = [], i in range(0, numberOfHobbys-1) |  
    acc + reduce(acc2 = 1, j in range(0, i-1) | acc2 * hLengths[j])
  ) AS multipliers,
  reduce(acc = [], i in range(0, numberOfHobbys-1) |
    acc + hs[i][
      toInt(combinationIndex/(reduce(acc2 = 1, j in range(0, i-1) | acc2 * hLengths[j]))) % hLengths[i]
    ]
  ) AS combinations
RETURN combinationIndex, indices, multipliers, combinations
```

The idea is the following: we multiply the number of potential values, e.g. for `['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3], [true, false]`, we calculate `n = 2×3×2 = 12`, using the first `reduce` in the query. We then iterate from 0 to n-1, and assign a row for each number, using the formula `a×1 + b×2 + c×6`, where a, b, c index the respective values, so all are non-negative integers and `a < 2`, `b < 3` and `c < 2`.

```
0×1 + 0×2 + 0×6 = 0
1×1 + 0×2 + 0×6 = 1
0×1 + 1×2 + 0×6 = 2
1×1 + 1×2 + 0×6 = 3
0×1 + 2×2 + 0×6 = 4
1×1 + 2×2 + 0×6 = 5
0×1 + 0×2 + 1×6 = 6
1×1 + 0×2 + 1×6 = 7
0×1 + 1×2 + 1×6 = 8
1×1 + 1×2 + 1×6 = 9
0×1 + 2×2 + 1×6 = 10
1×1 + 2×2 + 1×6 = 11
```

The result is:

```
╒════════════════╤═════════╤═══════════╤═════════════╕
│combinationIndex│indices  │multipliers│combinations │
╞════════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪═════════════╡
│0               │[0, 0, 0]│[1, 2, 6]  │[a, 1, true] │
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│1               │[1, 0, 0]│[1, 2, 6]  │[b, 1, true] │
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│2               │[0, 1, 0]│[1, 2, 6]  │[a, 2, true] │
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│3               │[1, 1, 0]│[1, 2, 6]  │[b, 2, true] │
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│4               │[0, 2, 0]│[1, 2, 6]  │[a, 3, true] │
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│5               │[1, 2, 0]│[1, 2, 6]  │[b, 3, true] │
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│6               │[0, 0, 1]│[1, 2, 6]  │[a, 1, false]│
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│7               │[1, 0, 1]│[1, 2, 6]  │[b, 1, false]│
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│8               │[0, 1, 1]│[1, 2, 6]  │[a, 2, false]│
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│9               │[1, 1, 1]│[1, 2, 6]  │[b, 2, false]│
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│10              │[0, 2, 1]│[1, 2, 6]  │[a, 3, false]│
├────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│11              │[1, 2, 1]│[1, 2, 6]  │[b, 3, false]│
└────────────────┴─────────┴───────────┴─────────────┘
```

So, for your problem, the query might look like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:likes]->(h:Hobby)-[:canDoAt]->(pl:Place)
WITH p, h, collect(pl.name) AS places
WITH p, collect(places) AS hs
WITH hs, size(hs) AS numberOfHobbys, reduce(acc = 1, h in hs | acc * size(h)) AS numberOfCombinations, extract(h IN hs | length(h)) AS hLengths
WITH hs, hLengths, numberOfHobbys, range(0, numberOfCombinations-1) AS combinationIndexes
UNWIND combinationIndexes AS combinationIndex
WITH
  reduce(acc = [], i in range(0, numberOfHobbys-1) |
    acc + hs[i][
      toInt(combinationIndex/(reduce(acc2 = 1, j in range(0, i-1) | acc2 * hLengths[j]))) % hLengths[i]
    ]
  ) AS combinations
RETURN combinations
```

This looks like this:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════╕
│combinations                        │
╞════════════════════════════════════╡
│[Diner, Lounge, Lake]               │
├────────────────────────────────────┤
│[Daves BarGrill, Lounge, Lake]      │
├────────────────────────────────────┤
│[Diner, Dive Bar, Lake]             │
├────────────────────────────────────┤
│[Daves BarGrill, Dive Bar, Lake]    │
├────────────────────────────────────┤
│[Diner, Lounge, Mountain]           │
├────────────────────────────────────┤
│[Daves BarGrill, Lounge, Mountain]  │
├────────────────────────────────────┤
│[Diner, Dive Bar, Mountain]         │
├────────────────────────────────────┤
│[Daves BarGrill, Dive Bar, Mountain]│
└────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Obviously, we would also like to get the person and the names of his/her hobbies:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:likes]->(h:Hobby)-[:canDoAt]->(pl:Place)
WITH p, h, collect([h.name, pl.name]) AS places
WITH p, collect(places) AS hs
WITH p, hs, size(hs) AS numberOfHobbys, reduce(acc = 1, h in hs | acc * size(h)) AS numberOfCombinations, extract(h IN hs | length(h)) AS hLengths
WITH p, hs, hLengths, numberOfHobbys, range(0, numberOfCombinations-1) AS combinationIndexes
UNWIND combinationIndexes AS combinationIndex
WITH
  p, reduce(acc = [], i in range(0, numberOfHobbys-1) |
    acc + [hs[i][
      toInt(combinationIndex/(reduce(acc2 = 1, j in range(0, i-1) | acc2 * hLengths[j]))) % hLengths[i]
    ]]
  ) AS combinations
RETURN p, combinations
```

The results:

```
╒═══════════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│p          │combinations                                                │
╞═══════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Diner], [drink, Lounge], [hike, Lake]]               │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Daves BarGrill], [drink, Lounge], [hike, Lake]]      │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Diner], [drink, Dive Bar], [hike, Lake]]             │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Daves BarGrill], [drink, Dive Bar], [hike, Lake]]    │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Diner], [drink, Lounge], [hike, Mountain]]           │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Daves BarGrill], [drink, Lounge], [hike, Mountain]]  │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Diner], [drink, Dive Bar], [hike, Mountain]]         │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: Joe}│[[eat, Daves BarGrill], [drink, Dive Bar], [hike, Mountain]]│
└───────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I might be overthinking this, so any comments are welcome.

An important remark: the fact that this is so complicated with pure Cypher is probably a good sign that you're better off calculating this from the client application.

Comment: accepting for the brilliantly thought out solution!. and yes, it may make more sense to write a simple query that lists person, hobbie, list(place) and do the rest in the cilent app

Comment: You are overthinking this, but it's still pretty impressive ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do this in cypher. What you are looking for is the Cartesian product of all places grouped by person and hobby.

```
A: [ [Joe, hike, Mountain], [Joe, hike, Lake] ]
B: [ [Joe, eat, Daves], [Joe, eat, Diner] ]
C: [ [Joe, drink, Lounge], [Joe, drink, Bar] ]
```

And you are looking for `A x B x C`.

As far as I know you can't group the return in Cypher like this. You should return all person, hobby, place rows and do this in a Python script where you build the grouped sets and calculate the Cartesian product.

The problem is that you get a lot of combinations with growing numbers of hobbies and places.